# Netra X4270: How do I enable the locator LED from command line (without iLOM)?

Tags: hardware, sun

Title says it all really - I have a bunch of servers in our lab that I want to set the locator LED on (so they can be identified and serviced). However the iLOM IP addresses are not accessible (the guy who has these is on leave).

How do I set the locator LED from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: the swiss-army-knife that is ipmitool!

The following command worked for me, although other HW types may need to use 'oem' commands:

`ipmitool chassis identify force`

This turns the LED on indefinitely (`chassis identify <interval>` should set it for the specified interval, but I didn't test this).

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipmitool) also lists a `sunoem led` command but doesn't explain their usage. Usage info is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19469-01/819-4363-12/ipmi_to_view_x4500.html#50528289_48944